# Lattice HDR-60 board download problem

Tags: fpga, lattice

I'm working on Lattice HDR-60 board which is pre loaded with a default program. When I try to load a program it disappears on restart. Recently I downloaded a design which downloaded successfully but didn't work. I restarted but now the INIT led is flickering and when I try to erase or download the default program it fails with the following error:

```
Error: Programming failed.
Failed to Open FTDI USB port. Make sure to select the right cable type.
```

Does anybody with some experience with lattice boards has any idea of where the probelm is coming from. I've searched through lattice website but no answer and as there are very few discussions on lattice products i thought i'll ask the question here and hope some kind soul will answer it. As I'm new to FPGA programming the problem is blocking me and I have no alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When LEDs "flicker", it suggests a power problem to me.

Ensure that your board is getting clean stable power, and not being parasitically powered through the programmer's data lines or similar.

Comment: that was it! I can't believe i missed this. thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you please share what was the design software used to program HDR60?